# How to write web API to consume SharePoint list data to expose it to other platforms

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, api, graph-api

I need to write a webapi to consume data  and doing CRUD operation in SharePoint list.I am little bit confused about how to to that. Please give some suggestions or reference for this one.